# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when building my react app

Tags: arrays, reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, react-props

while building my react app for deployment, I am getting this error

**TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

when I am rending on port3000 I did not see this error but only get it while building the app.

Can anyone assist to resolve this?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./Tabs.module.css"

const Tabs = ({ children}) => {
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState (children [0].props.label);

    const handleClick =( e, newActiveTab ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setActiveTab(newActiveTab);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <ul className= {styles.tabs}>
                {children.map ((tab) => {
                    const label = tab.props.label;
                    return (
                    <li
                    className= {label == activeTab ? styles.current : ""} 
                    key= {label}
                    >
                      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => handleClick (e, label)}>{label}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
            {children.map ((tabcontent1) => {
                if (tabcontent1.props.label == activeTab)
                return (
                <div key= {tabcontent1.props.label} className= {styles.content}>{tabcontent1.props.children} 
                </div>
                );
            })}
            
        </div>
       
    );
}

export default  Tabs ;
```

Comment: `children [0]` isn't defined yet. `children` prop isn't really an array, you should use the top-level [Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) to map children components. Are you using SSR with Nextjs?

Comment: Your page is probably getting statically rendered. so, on build time `children` is undefined. And next js is trying to render it statically, so it access the initial states where it is trying to do `undefined[0]` which is an error. So, make your children variable available for static side rendering.

Comment: @rakesh shrestha. Thanks for your contribution. kindly express the code to make the children variable for static side rendering

Comment: yes i use SSR but  i think i did not define it , please assist

Answer (score 0):

In next js, when you don't put `export const getServerSideProps = () => {}` in your page then that page is automatically subjected to static side rendering. On development mode, you may see a lightening symbol on bottom-right. Anyway you can read the docs on `data-fetching` on nextjs. However, your issue on this situation can be easily fixed by setting the children through `useEffect`.

```js
// handle null on your active tab render function
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
 if(children.length)
  children[0].props.label
}, [children])
```

Another Code Sample:
*A simple change in code structure and the way you are trying to do. It's on react but kind of same in next as well *

```js
import React from "react";

const Tabs = ({ tabsData }) => {
  const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const switchTabs = (index) => setActiveTabIndex(index);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: 20, cursor: "pointer" }}>
      {/* Here active tab is given a green color and non actives grey */}
      {tabsData.map((x, i) => (
        <div
          key={i}
          style={{ color: activeTabIndex === i ? "green" : "#bbb" }}
          onClick={() => switchTabs(i)}
        >
          {x.label}
        </div>
      ))}
      {/* Show Active Tab Content */}
      {tabsData[activeTabIndex].content}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  // You can place it inside tabs also in this case
  // but lets say you have some states on this component
  const tabsData = React.useMemo(() => {
    return [
      // content can be any component or React Element
      { label: "Profile", content: <p>Verify all Input</p> },
      { label: "Settings", content: <p>Settings Input</p> },
      { label: "Info", content: <p>INput info</p> }
    ];
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tabs tabsData={tabsData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is also a example sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-night-ufqr5?file=/src/App.js:0-1219

Comment: When i add the above line of code - Firstly the Tabs was not active until I press it. it was blank. and while building i got an error  -  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at Tabs.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction on code sandbox?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have all the tabbed component on codesandbox now. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-joana-wsib8?file=/src/index.js . what I am having now is = TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

when building the entire project.

Comment: i haven't got any reply from you @rakeshshrestha,

Comment: sorry @GMERT you just copy pasted your whole code without proper components. There is no way I can run that on my machine. Please provide a working small demo so that I can make proper edits on it. You can do it on react codesandbox as well. I will update it for next.

Comment: Thanks so much @rakeshshrestha. i just updated the basic code as there is no how I can shorting it than this so that it can be easy to run on your machine. please help me check. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-joana-wsib8?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @GMERT Thanks for the repro. Any way I have updated my answer with new way thought it might help you.